# Code inserts only the last row. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two columns `boatRegNum` and `Payerret`.

`boatRegNum` is character data type and `Payerret` is money datatype.

We are using a GridView to create dynamic rows. The first row is created by default.

On this first row, user enters value for `boatRegNum` and `Payerret`. For purpose of demonstration, the value for `boatRegNum` in first row is `B3098` and value for `Payerret` for same row is `530.000`.

Then the user clicks the "Add New Row" button to add an additional row. In the newly added row, the user enters `TY000` for `boatRegNum` and `90.00` for same second row.

The issue we are having so far is that when these values are inserted into the database, only the value for second row is inserted into the database. The value for the first row is always ignored.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Below are relevant code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Markup:

```
<%foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dtAirInfoTable.Rows)
{%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="form-control" style="width: 493px; color: #0093B2; font-weight: bold;">
            <%=Convert.ToString(row.ItemArray[1].ToString())%></span>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <span class="form-control txtPayerret" style="width: 326px; color: #0093B2; font-weight: bold;">
            <%=Convert.ToString(row.ItemArray[2].ToString())%></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

C#:

```
// datatable CurrTable
private DataTable LoadTable1(bool createIfMissing)
{
    const string ViewStateKey = "CurrTable";

    DataTable dt = ViewState[ViewStateKey] as DataTable;

    if (createIfMissing)
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("boatregNum", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Payerret", typeof(string)));

            ViewState[ViewStateKey] = dt;
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 1;
            dr["boatregNum"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Payerret"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}

private void SetInitialRow()
{
    myMultiView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

    DataTable dt = LoadTable1(true);

    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}

DataTable regtable = ViewState["CurrTable"] as DataTable;    

foreach (DataRow row in regtable.Rows)
{
    string txBoatRegNum = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    string txTaxPayerRet = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();

    //prevent money data types from breaking. If user does not enter value, then enter 0 in its place
    //This sub will store Marine and Vessel info to the database.
    if (txTaxPayerRet != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txTaxPayerRet))
        {
            txTaxPayerRet = "0";
        }

        SqlCommand aircmd = new SqlCommand("sp_saveInfo", conn);
        aircmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        aircmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", accountnumber.Text);
        aircmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eID", Request["pageId"]);
        aircmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tID", tPayerID);
        aircmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txYr", txtTaxYr.Text);
        aircmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", txBoatRegNum);
        aircmd.Parameters.Add("@txretval", SqlDbType.Money).Value = decimal.Parse(txTaxPayerRet); //convert text back to money

        aircmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_saveInfo] 
    @pid INT,
    @eID INT,
    @txYr INT,
    @regno VARCHAR(50),
    @txretval DECIMAL(18, 2),
    @tID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRAN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Info WHERE pid = @pid)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Info 
        SET EquipmentTypeID = @eID,
            TaxYear = @txYr,
            AirCraftRegNo = @regno,
            TaxPyrRetdVal = @txretval
        WHERE pid = @pid
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [dbo].Info (pid, TaxYear, AirCraftRegNo, EquipmentTypeID, TaxPyrRetdVal, TaxpayerID)
        VALUES (@pid, @txYr, @regno, @eID, @txretval, @tID)
    END

    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Comment: You're using scalar variables to in your insert statement. A scalar can hold only one value at a time, so you'll only ever insert 1 rows worth of data at a time. The reason you're getting the last value is because The 1st value gets pushed out by the 2nd and so on... The last row has nothing to knock out of the way, so that's what you get.

Comment: Help me sir, how would I change that?

I am suspecting you meant the Stored Procedure.

Comment: I can show you the syntax using straight sql but I'm useless when it comes to XML & JSON... Actually, I got an exable of XML being passed into a proc and parsed into a table. I didn't write the XML part... Let me see what I can find.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem... I was able to find one that looked pretty straight forward.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Found it...Notice that, aside from passing concertin varchar to xml, no scalar variables are being used. The developer is simply parsing the xml in a select, directly into the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcName
/*
* mm/ff/yyyy xx, TASK:INC00000.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
*/
@sXML VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;

      -- Change the VARCHAR(MAX) to XML data type.
      DECLARE @XML XML = @sXML;

      -- create a new temp table...
      IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XMLTABLE', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
         DROP TABLE #XMLTABLE;

        CREATE TABLE #XMLTABLE (
            ItemNumberOne INT NOT NULL,
            UserID INT NOT NULL,
            ItemNumber3 INT NOT NULL,
            Priority SMALLINT NOT NULL,
            ActionType VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL
            );
        -- insert the shreaded xml into the #temp table
        INSERT INTO #XMLTABLE (UserPayorForInvoiceReviewID,UserID,PayorID,Priority,ActionType)
        SELECT
            ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemList.Item.query('./ItemNumberOne')    .value('.','INT'), 0), -1),
            ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemList.Item.query('./UserID')           .value('.','INT'), 0), -1),
            ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemList.Item.query('./ItemNumber3')      .value('.','INT'), 0), -1),
            ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemList.Item.query('./Priority')         .value('.','SMALLINT'), 0), -1),
            ItemList.Item.query('./ActionType')                     .value('.','VARCHAR(3)') ActionType
        FROM 
            @XML.nodes('/ItemList/Item') AS ItemList(Item);

        -- There's more to the rest of the procedure below
        -- but the the xml data is loaded into the temp table.
```

Hopefully you'll be able to fill in the remaining blanks.